# Calling "fix geometries" in the QGIS python console?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to use the "fix geometries" tool in the Python console in QGIS.
However, I can't find anywhere, how to function is called and how to use it as code.
I tried

```
QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer(input_path, output_path)
```

But I guess this is wrong, since it does not work. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call fix geometries algorithm as follows in pyqgis:

```
import processing
layer = iface.activeLayer()
fix_layer = processing.run("native:fixgeometries", {'INPUT':layer,'OUTPUT':'memory:'})['OUTPUT']
```

I tried it in qgis 3.10

Comment: Can you recommend a website or anything alike where to look up all the commands? For me it seems like the information is kind of scattered across several websites. I always take ages to find information on how to call which tool.

Comment: @blumige_statistik to know how to run a processing algorithm I do the following: I run the algorithm and then go to the menu Processing > History > and then select the last algorithm executed. When you select it you can see how to run it using pyqgis.

Comment: This answer can help you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/372681/120426

Comment: The pyQGIS API documentation is also a good resource. https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/