# (QGIS) Get Python code from call

Tags: pyqgis

Is it possible to retrieve Python code based on the action performed?

I am not very familiar with Python and I would like to know what code could be implemented based on what I just did from the menu.  For example, when I join attributes by location, I want to know what code would have been used if I had run the same action using Python.

Comment: What menu exactly are you referring to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the processing history with the shortcut "Ctrl+Alt+H" or in the `Processing` tab click on `History`

https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing/history.html

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!